# Compare consecutive dataframe rows based on columns in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe. It has data about suppliers. If the name of the supplier and group are same, number of units should ideally be the same. However, sometimes that is not the case. I am writing code that imports data from SQL into Python then compares for these numbers.

This is for Python 3. Importing the data into Python was easy. I am a Python rookie. To make things easier for myself, I created individual dataframes for each supplier to compare numbers instead of looking at the whole dataframe at once.

```
supp = data['Supplier']
supplier = []
for s in supp:
    if s not in Supplier:
        supplier.append(s)

su = "Authentic Brands Group LLC"
deal = defaultdict(list)
blist = []
glist = []
columns = ['Supplier','ID','Units','Grp']
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
def add_row(df3, row):
    df3.loc[-1] = row
    df3.index = df3.index + 1  
    return df3.sort_index()

for row in data.itertuples():
    for x in supplier:
        s1 = row.Supplier
        if  s1 == su:
            if row.Supplier_Group not in glist:
                glist.append(row.Supplier_Group)
            for g in range(len(glist)):
                if glist[g]==row.Supplier_Group:
                    supp = x
                    blist=[]
                    blist.append(row.ID)
                    blist.append(row.Units)
                    blist.append(glist[g])
                    add_row(df3,[b1,row.ID,row.Units,glist[g]])   
                    break
            break                     
        break
for i in range(1,len(df3)):
    if df3.Supplier.loc[i] == df3.Supplier.loc[i-1] and df3.Grp.loc[i] == df3.Grp.loc[i-1]:
        print(df3.Supplier,df3.Grp)
```

This gives me a small subset that looks like this:

[image]

Now I want to look at the supplier name and Grp, if they are same as others in dataframe, Units should be same. In this case, row 2 is incorrect. Units should be 100. I want to add another column to this dataframe that says 'False' if the number of Units is correct. This is the tricky part for me. I can iterate over the rows, but I'm unsure how to compare them and add column.

I'm stuck at this point.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is your logic for determining which value of units is correct?  Is the first record of that group always correct?  Is it the most popular number ('mode')?

Comment: The number of units should be the same within the group. In this case, for Group A, the new column should say 'False' for all three rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of your data in a single dataframe, `df`, you can do the following:

```
grp_by_cols = ['Supplier', 'ID', 'Grp']
all_cols = grp_by_cols + ['Unit']
res_df = df.assign(first_unit=lambda df: df.loc[:, all_cols]
                                           .groupby(grp_by_cols)
                                           .transform('first'))\
           .assign(incorrect=lambda df: df['Unit'] == df['first_unit'])\
           .assign(incorrect=lambda df: df.loc[:, grp_by_cols + ['incorrect']])\
                                          .groupby(grp_by_cols)
                                          .transform(np.any))
```

The first call to `assign` adds a single new column (called `'first_unit'`) that is the first value of "Unit" for each group of Supplier/ID/Grp (see `grp_by_cols`).

The second call to `assign` adds a column called `'incorrect'` that is `True` when `'Unit'` doesn't equal `'first_unit'`. The third and final `assign` call overwrites that column to be `True` if *any* rows in that group are `True`. You can remove that if that's not what you want.

Then, if you want to look at the results for a single supplier, you can do something like:

```
res_df.query('Supplier = "Authentic Brands Group"')
```